# Dealing with recurrent investments during significant financial crysis

Tags: investing, investment-strategies, european-union

About six months ago I have started using about 12-15% of my monthly salary to invest in various instruments:

- a small amount in the [supplementary voluntary pension insurance, III pillar](https://ec.europa.eu/economy_finance/publications/pages/publication16034_en.pdf) (half covered by employer, tax free money)
- the same amount of the above in another III pillar fund
- similar amounts in five mutual funds (EUR and local currency) offered by the primary bank I am working with. These have various risks and now my loss is estimated between 4 (the most conservatory) and 12% (the most risky one).

Location: non-EUR European Union country (Eastern-Europe).

The financial crisis has also affected the pension funds, but I am mostly interested in how to deal the mutual funds.

I am very inclined to simply let payments go those funds (not sell, invest monthly as before), but I am not sure that my reasoning is correct:

#### Pros (for keeping recurrent investments)

- as long as I am not out of liquidity, buying when unit cost is low might get a significant income increase when markets will recover (possibly several years from now)
- I still get my full salary (IT job strongly connected to food distribution which is less affected than other sectors, allows fully remote work). Even if that changes, my expenses are significantly reduced due to being stuck in home (I live in a country that will be severely hit by SARS-CoV-2 and heavy restrictions are already set up).

Very roughly, under current circumstances about 50% of the income covers the expenses, ~15% are the investments.

#### Cons

- The stock prices of the company I work for reduced with more than 40% in about 6 months *before* the COVID related crisis and I expect it to have significant financial trouble in the near future (not sure about the causality, but such a drop in stock price seems very bad to me)
- I expect a major economical crisis to come soon. The 2008-2009 led to almost freezing any hiring in my country (including IT sector), so getting another job might prove very challenging.
- major personal risk - if the virus gets to me and I need hospitalization I am as good as dead, as the health system in my country is completely overrun by this type of infection.

I am interested if my line of reasoning makes sense or I should consider other factors as well when dealing with keeping the payments being done for the mutual funds.

Comment: I would start by researching the funds you're indirectly investing in.  If it's some type of mutual fund you can usually get a list of its top 10 holdings online.  Look each of the top 10 holdings up and try to find what the smart money is currently doing.  Are insiders currently buying?  If so perhaps you should continue averaging down like you seem to be doing.  Regardless though, they say you should only invest what you could stand to lose, and in normal times it's usually suggested to have 6 months of living expenses in liquid cash.  When times are tough, perhaps you need a bigger cushion

Comment: @publicwireless - yes, the warning "invest only if you afford to lose" is displayed on several occasions when using the interface for investment, so I only invested what I can lose.For the low risk ones, they are clearly investing in government bonds or similar, for the others I will have to look. Ref to "liquid cash" (6 months): you are referring to easy to use money, not actual cash, right? For that I am prepared for about 12 months, but nothing is sure in this period. Thanks.

Comment: @publicwireless You may consider developing your comment into an answer because it contains useful information for other folks in the future (especially for newbies when it comes to personal finances).

Comment: By liquid cash I mean anything that can be quickly and easily withdrawn without penalty and without being subject to loss when markets go down.  So a savings or checking account at a bank would do.  However, having your 'safety net' living expenses in stocks would be dangerous because if the time comes when you need the money and markets are down, then you're forced to sell at a loss.

Comment: By the way, when I say 6 months that's a general rule of thumb for US citizens.  US is lucky in that there are many safety net social programs available like unemployment assistance and $1200 stimulus checks which they're about to send.  Your country will be different and hence you need to possibly have a larger safety net to cover a longer period of time to pay expenses in case of global economic disaster.  US can basically print it's way out of Depression due to USD status as global reserve currency, but other nations are not that fortunate.